# Why i concat() 3 df and still NaN valaue?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

my code:

```
dfs = [df_uk_rfmt, df_uk_clv, df_uk_prod_pen]

final_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis = 1)

final_df.head()
```

And my new df looks like this:

[image]

but when I using Microsoft Query, Some NaN has value for example on CustomerID 12748 on this pic:

[image]

PS. All df index = CustomerID

My purpose is to join 3 data frames with full outer.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of 3 dfs? This is too ambiguous

Comment: Yes sir.

df_uk_rfmt: https://prnt.sc/X4RGdA1StZjB
df_uk_clv: https://prnt.sc/BUOOgOkgZLIx
df_uk_prod_pen: https://prnt.sc/4eBrkVgHXs9l

Comment: quite interesting... should work by defaut...
can you please share more code you use? especially how `df_uk_rfmt, df_uk_clv, df_uk_prod_pen` are created and manipulated (if any manipulations were done before that final concat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before defining `dfs` you need to make sure you do not have MultiIndex. So, do this:

```
df_uk_rfmt = df_uk_rfmt.reset_index()
df_uk_clv = df_uk_clv.reset_index()
df_uk_prod_pen = df_uk_prod_pen.reset_index()
```

Then

```
dfs = [df_uk_rfmt, df_uk_clv, df_uk_prod_pen]
final_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis = 1)
final_df.head()
```